# How to copy an int to a boost/std::array of char?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-asio

What is the most simple and efficient why to copy an int to a boost/std::array?

The following seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate way to do it:

```
  int r = rand();
  boost::array<char, sizeof(int)> send_buf;
  std::copy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r + sizeof(int)), &send_buf[0]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for comparison, here's the same thing with memcpy:

```
#include <cstring>

int r = rand();
boost::array<char, sizeof(int)> send_buf;
std::memcpy(&send_buf[0], &r, sizeof(int));
```

Your call whether an explosion of casts (and the opportunity to get them wrong) is better or worse than the C++ "sin" of using a function also present in C ;-)

Personally I think `memcpy` is quite a good "alarm" for this kind of operation, for the same reason that C++-style casts are a good "alarm" (easy to spot while reading, easy to search for). But you might prefer to have the same alarm for everything, in which case you can cast the arguments of `memcpy` to `void*`.

Btw, I might use `sizeof r` for both sizes rather than `sizeof(int)`, but it sort of depends whether the context demands that the array "is big enough for r (which happens to be an int)" or "is the same size as an int (which r happens to be)". Since it's a send buffer, I guess the buffer is the size that the wire protocol demands and `r` is supposed to match the buffer, rather than the other way around. So `sizeof(int)` is probably appropriate but `4` or `PROTOCOL_INTEGER_SIZE` might be more appropriate still.

Comment: There is a missing reference operator "&" in `memcpy(&send_buf[0], r, sizeof(int))`. Should be instead `memcpy(&send_buf[0], &r, sizeof(int))`.

Comment: You can replace the last line of code with `std::memcpy(send_buf.begin(), &r, sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 3):

The idea is correct, but you have a bug:

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r + sizeof(int))
```

Should be:

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r) + sizeof(int)
```

or

```
reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r+1)
```

These or a `memcpy` equivalent are OK. Anything else risks alignment issues.

Answer (score 2):

It's common currency to use `reinterpret_cast` for those purposes but the Standard makes it pretty clear that `static_cast` via `void*` is perfectly acceptable. In fact in the case of a type like `int` then `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r)` is *defined* to have the semantics of `static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&r))`. Why not be explicit and use that outright?

If you get into the habit, you have less chance in the future of using a `reinterpret_cast` which will end up having implementation-defined semantics rather than a `static_cast` chain which will always have well-defined semantics.

Do note that you're allowed to treat a pointer to a single object as if it were a pointer into an array of one (cf. 5.7/4). This is convenient for obtaining the second pointer.

```
int r = rand();
boost::array<char, sizeof(int)> send_buf;
auto cast = [](int* p) { return static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(p)); };
std::copy(cast(&r), cast(&r + 1), &send_buf[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor bug as pointed out by Michael Anderson

But you could do this:

```
#include <iostream>

union U
{
    int  intVal;
    char charVal[sizeof(int)];
};

int main()
{
    U   val;
    val.intVal  = 6;

    std::cout <<  (int)val.charVal[0] << ":" << (int)val.charVal[1] << ":" << (int)val.charVal[2] << ":" << (int)val.charVal[3] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Whereas this of course works, it is still UB, since you're reading from a union member that wasn't written to.

Comment: You don't seem to have actually copied the int into a boost/std array of char ;-p

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes I have lost that argument before and conceded it is UB. Though if you happen to know the part of the standard that states it I would love to know. Because so much C code relies on the above behavior I would have (before previous discussion) have though it perfectly legal.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Would it help if I had done: `std::array<U,1> val;` ;-)

Comment: @Loki: in C++03 it follows from what 9.5 says about only one member being active. There's text "one special guarantee" is made about PODs with a common initial sequence. No other special guarantees are made. In this case your union type-puns as `char`, which is a legal alias, I'm not sure I can "prove" it UB. The usual int/float example certainly is UB in C++03. C99 OTOH contains more special guarantees to say that you can reinterpret object representations through a union, and it does so in order to bless what compilers were doing anyway. I haven't checked the situation in C++11.

Comment: @SteveJessop: In C++11 (or n3376) It basically says what you say above about one member being active (and the initial sequence bit).